# XSL get values from input XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I seem to get stuck on getting the correct form of xsl-value. I have the following XML INPUT:

```
<root>
<output>
    <tagQ>
        <tag name="X">
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="id">83683</parameter>
            </parameters>
            <tagE/>
            <tagR>
                <R id="1">
                    <column name="A">83683</column>
                    <column name="B">7260</column>
                    <column name="C">10</column>
                    <column name="D">2500</column>
                </R>
            </tagR>
        </tag>
    </tagQ>
</output>
```

And the desired OUTPUT is:

```
<newRoot>
<output>
    <tagQ>
        <tag name="another">
            <parameters>
                <parameter name="A">83683</parameter>
                <parameter name="B">7260</parameter>
                <parameter name="C">10</parameter>
                <parameter name="D">2500</parameter> *//value of columns from input//*
            </parameters>
        </tag>
    </tagQ>
</output>
</newRoot>
```

Thank you for your help. I have updated the question with the current XSL that I have. output is good, but i cant seem to figure out how to get the actual values

Edit:
Current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <newRoot>
        <output>
            <tagQ>
                <tag name="another">
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="A">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@*[@A]"/>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter name="B">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@*[@A]"/>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter name="C">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@*[@A]"/>
                        </parameter>
                        <parameter name="D">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@*[@A]"/>
                        </parameter>
                    </parameters>
                </tag>
            </tagQ>
        </output>
    </newRoot>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: **1.** Where exactly are you stuck with this? **2.** Where did the value of "0000" come from?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and the incorrect output it is producing.

Comment: Corrected with the value tag name="another".

Comment: updated with the current XSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[@A]"/>
```

does not select anything. You are in the context of the `root` element - and your expression tries to select any attribute (of the current node) that has a child attribute named `A`. Of course, no such animal can exist.

You would have had more success with:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//column[@name='A']"/>
```

which selects a descendant element named `column` whose `name` attribute is  `"A"`.

However, I'd suggest you try a different approach - one that lets XSLT's recursive processing model do the heavy lifting:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <newRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newRoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag[@name='X']">
    <tag name="another">
        <parameters>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tagR/R/column"/>
        </parameters>
    </tag>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column">
    <parameter>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parameter>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you, you are right! one more question..if i wanted to change the output of  attribute name <parameter name="A">83683</parameter> and i wanted instead name="whatever", how would u go with the template match? same values, just a different name for the attirbute "name"

Comment: I am afraid you have confused me: If you want to have `name="whatever"` that would change the **value** of the `name` attribute. But then you say  "*just a different **name** for the attirbute "name"*"; that would result in `whatever="A"`.

Comment: "f you want to have name="whatever" that would change the value of the name attribute" - that's correct. The value of the name attribute I meant. sorry

Comment: More exactly if I want the output <parameter name="what1">83683</parameter>
                <parameter name="what2">7260</parameter>
                <parameter name="what3">10</parameter>
                <parameter name="what4">2500</parameter>. getting the same values for the parameter element, but change the value of the 'name' attribute . hope it's more clear now.

Comment: You would probably want to add a template matching the `@name` attribute and specify the new value there. I am not sure where the new value would be coming from, though.